# Navigation Bar in View Based App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am working on a view based app in iphone, i want to show the Navigation bar when it is loaded, i am using  `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` in viewdidload function, but it is still showing the same simple view without the navigation bar at the top, what's the problem

Comment: do you have a navigation controller in your project?

Comment: i am using view based app, default right now, i only added the above code right now

Comment: web based app? do you mean your app is being accessed by safari or that you have a UIWebView on one of your views. In any case, you need to have a UINavigationController to show navigation bar. Alternate solution would be to have a navigation bar from IB on your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Xcode4 then do this in app delegate.

```
   self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *navcontrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navcontrol;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `NavigationBar` to your view.
calling this should sort it out

```
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
```